# Having difficulty accessing JSON file from an api - receiving 403 error (works from another server, however)

Tags: json, windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

When accessing https://api.weather.gov/products/fead3465-2e6f-4350-ae90-15aaa61b91ff to retrieve a JSON string, I'm receiving a (403): Forbidden error. The same code is successful using another another URL (http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/json/nwstext_search.py?sts=2019-04-15T00:00Z&ets=2019-04-18T00:00Z&awipsid=PNSBOX), however, that URL is not as robust as api.weather.gov.

I'm not sure if I need to emulate browser credentials to access this JSON from the api. I'm writing the code using Windows Powershell 2.0 (cannot upgrade, unfortunately).

```
$url = "https://api.weather.gov/products/fead3465-2e6f-4350-ae90-15aaa61b91ff"  
$WebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$WebRequest.Method = "GET"
$WebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
$WebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$Response = $WebRequest.GetResponse()
$ResponseStream = $Response.GetResponseStream()
$ReadStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $ResponseStream
$data = $ReadStream.ReadToEnd()

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
$ser = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$json = $ser.DeserializeObject($data)
echo $json
```

Expecting to see the JSON, but getting a (403): Forbidden error.

Comment: What happens if you change the content type to "application/ld+json"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [FAQ for this api](https://www.weather.gov/documentation/services-web-api#), I see them mention the UserAgent. I was able to get this to run for me if I specify another `UserAgent`. I would review their license for the API to ensure that this is a valid/legal way to access this API to ensure you are not accessing it against their terms of use.

```
$url = "https://api.weather.gov/products/fead3465-2e6f-4350-ae90-15aaa61b91ff"  
$WebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$WebRequest.Method = "GET"
$WebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
$WebRequest.UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.500.0 Safari/534.6'
$Response = $WebRequest.GetResponse()
$ResponseStream = $Response.GetResponseStream()
$ReadStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $ResponseStream
$data = $ReadStream.ReadToEnd()

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
$ser = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$json = $ser.DeserializeObject($data)
echo $json
```

Comment: Thanks @Brandon McClure. I added that line and get the following error: 

_"Unable to find type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At C:\Users\TruVuAdmin\Documents\GetPNS.ps1:28 char:70
+   $WebRequest.UserAgent = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent] <<<< ::Chrome
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...nds.PSUserAgent:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound"_

Comment: @wxmanajb, I just edited the answer to use the string value of the chrome property of the PSUserAgent class. Can you please try that?